# EF Data Annotation - Foreign Key - How to Customize

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, data-annotations

My issue is the following.  I have a Model for an Address table as follows.

```
public partial class ADDRESS
{
    public ADDRESS()
    {
        this.ADDRESS_ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid ADDRESS_ID { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS_LINE { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public Guid? STATE_ID { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
}
```

This ADDRESS model is used throughout my application and has different validation requirements depending on where it is placed within a form.

I am wondering if there is a way to customize the data annotations.  For example, the ADDRESS_LINE and CITY properties are required for OCCUPATION_ADDRESS but not required for WORK_LOCATION_ADDRESS.

```
public class OCCUPATION_DETAILS
{
    public string COMPANY_NAME { get; set; }
    public string JOB_TITLE { get; set; }
    etc...

    public Guid OCCUPATION_ADDRESS_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ADDRESS OCCUPATION_ADDRESS { get; set; }

    public WORK_LOCATION_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ADDRESS WORK_LOCATION_ADDRESS { get; set; }

}
```

Or it could be that basic validation is the same (zip has to be 5 digits), but I need to adjust the "DisplayName" that is used to match the label of the form it is within.

Trying to minimize the amount of copied models I have set up; otherwise maintenance will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by using the idea of inheritance
how?

```
public abstract class ADDRESS
{
    public ADDRESS()
    {
        this.ADDRESS_ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid ADDRESS_ID { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS_LINE { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public Guid? STATE_ID { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
}

public parital class OCCUPATION_ADDRESS: ADDRESS,IValidatableObject
{
   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
       if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ADDRESS_LINE))
          yield return new ValidationResult("Address line is required!",new string[]{"ADDRESS_LINE"});
   }
}

public parital class WORK_LOCATION_ADDRESS: ADDRESS,IValidatableObject
{
   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {

   }
}

// and your Occupation details class will be like: instead of ADDRESS you will use the corresponding derived classes
public class OCCUPATION_DETAILS
{
    public string COMPANY_NAME { get; set; }
    public string JOB_TITLE { get; set; }
    etc...

    public Guid OCCUPATION_ADDRESS_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual OCCUPATION_ADDRESS OCCUPATION_ADDRESS { get; set; }

    public WORK_LOCATION_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual WORK_LOCATION_ADDRESS WORK_LOCATION_ADDRESS { get; set; }

}
```

and the inheritance should be Table per Hierarchy (TPH)

for more information about TPH check this [Table per hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

hope that this will help you

regards